# Intercepting html5 video play event in android web view

Tags: android, android-webview

In my Android web view i want to intercept the html5 video play event.

In my web page i have embedded videos, on which if i click play then the play event should be captured in web view and i then open it through Android video player.

My problem is that i don't own the web content so not able to add a custom java script function for video load and then intercepting through my web view's JavaScriptInterface.

I have always seen example of intercepting custom java script functions but is it possible intercept video.play events which is not my custom function.

I tried with on touch listener but again in the hit results i am not getting any element id :(.

Thanks and Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

i found that you have to delegate to a JS function on the onMetadata event of your video element in the html . The JS function would in turn call the android's javascriptinterface's method.

Once you get callback to the method , you can do your own stuff.

also found that there is no way to intercept play event of Android's media player.

cheers,
Saurav